# Something wrong with data parsing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, coffeescript

I have got some problem with a parsing data on server.
here is my json data

```
ajax = (in_url,in_data,in_succes)->
    _url = in_url
    _data = in_data
    _success = in_succes
    #_error = in_error
    $.ajax
            type: "GET"
            url: _url
            data: _data
            dataType:"json"
            contentType:"json"
            success:_success
saveNewComplex:->
        data = ko.toJS model.complex
        ajax "/Complex/SaveNewComplex",data, () -> alert "Success"
        @getAllComplex()
```

And there is my server-side code

```
public ActionResult SaveNewComplex(string complexName, string complexDescript,  List<string> complexItems)
        {
            var temp = complexItems;
            return null;
        }
```

[image: JSONData]

Here is a picture with query parameters after all array member strange squere brackets - maybe it is main problem?
[image]

Strange result on server - all is null.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong than you are trying to send `array` to your `MVC controller`. If this is the case than you should first stringify your array at client side and than send the string to server, after that on server you can deserialize your string to get your array, you should do something like :

**Js**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'your url',
type: 'POST',
data: ko.toJSON(yourArray)
});
```

**On server**

```
public ActionResult SaveNewComplex(string yourArrayString)
{
       var temp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourArrayString);      
       //temp contains your array
}
```

Comment: You are right i am trying send array to server but array is a part of object. And you can see that i have stringify my object in saveNewComplex method. I tried your tipe but I have null error. Thanks for trying help.

Comment: In saveNewComplex method you are not stringify, there you are using `ko.toJS` which actually unwrapped all observables and give you a clean JS object. To stringify you should use `ko.toJSON`.

Comment: Ou thanks), but it is not working =(...maybe you see some more errors in this code? and when i am stringify it - like on image 2 query string is anout 5 parameters(name,description and array parts) not 1 string( lilke in your example)

Comment: Thanks a lot) you are like a wizard) i am fully - the problem with corectness of your advise was in cash of my browser) thanks a lot. Sorry but i still cant add  + for you,sorry.

Comment: @РоманИванов you are wellcome